# Navigator crash while using with Keepout filter

Tags: navigation, ros2, nav2

On a ROS2 humble robot running on a RPI4, when using navigator with keepout filters, it stops working after a while. On the console we get a complaint about not receiving a heartbeat from navigator, this shutting down the container. Is there a way we can increase this 4000 ms?

See log below

```
Oct 01 15:24:07 caretta navigator-start[4822]: [component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1696173847.120296521] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Have not received a heartbeat from bt_navigator. 
Oct 01 15:24:07 caretta navigator-start[4822]: [component_container_isolated-1] [ERROR] [1696173847.120483243] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: CRITICAL FAILURE: SERVER bt_navigator IS DOWN after not receiving a heartbeat for 4000 ms. Shutting down related nodes. 
Oct 01 15:24:07 caretta navigator-start[4822]: [component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1696173847.120620095] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Terminating bond timer...
Oct 01 15:24:07 caretta navigator-start[4822]: [component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1696173847.120674798] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Resetting managed nodes... 
Oct 01 15:24:07 caretta navigator-start[4822]: [component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1696173847.120718095] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Deactivating velocity_smoother
```

Comment: I don't see a crash error message, did you clip something?

Comment: [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: CRITICAL FAILURE: SERVER bt_navigator IS DOWN after not receiving a heartbeat for 4000 ms. Shutting down related nodes. -- was not visible

Comment: Anything before then? That's the consequence of a failure, not a failure itself